# How to make assertions in Chisel be just warnings and not stop simulation

Tags: riscv, chisel

We have added assertions to our Chisel code, but we only want them to warn, not stop the simulation.  Is there a way to tell Chisel to do this?

For example:

assert(x(1) =/= nxt_val(1))

We want this to just give us a warning, so we can collect the log, to find places where clock gating is most effective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you just write a method that you pass the condition and perhaps a behavior flag.

```
object warnAssert {
  def apply(condition: Bool, message: String = "", isFatal: Boolean = false) {
    (isFatal, message.isEmpty) {
      case (true, true)   => assert(condition)
      case (true, false)  => assert(condition, message)
      case (false, _) => when(bool) { printf("Warning: %s\n", message) // line number should get included here
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Chick's answer is reasonable, although I suspect you're looking for something that Verilog simulators register as an error rather than a printf.

Unfortunately the simulation construct support in FIRRTL is pretty primitive--assert emitting `$fatal` is an example of this. We generally have dealt with this via FIRRTL transforms, or simulator-specific stuff (implementing see our [Verilator testing top](https://github.com/freechipsproject/firrtl/blob/3243f05a69b4b77761699be412f349a9b8b9193f/src/test/resources/firrtl/testTop.cpp#L12) for example). As discussed at the CCC, I think we should invest more effort in better simulation libraries. If you have ideas and suggestions, it would be super helpful if you could package them up in an RFC: https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues.